# How to align WPF table to center of another table?

Tags: c#, wpf

The answer might be in two line. I searched everywhere but ended up no where.

I have a nested table (Table inside another table) . How can I align the table horizontally to center of the current cell?

I want the answers for WPF.

Here is the sample code:

```
//Create new Table
Table myTable = new Table();
// Add a column
myTable.Columns.Add(new TableColumn() { Width = new GridLength(500) });
TableRowGroup trg = new TableRowGroup();
// Create new Row element
TableRow currentRow = new TableRow();
// Add another table to the Cell
currentRow.Cells.Add(AnotherTable);
trg.Rows.Add(currentRow);
myTable.RowGroups.Add(trg);
```

It's System.Windows.Documents.Table class.

Comment: There is no such thing as a Table element in WPF... do you mean the Grid element perhaps?

Comment: Can you show us some code ? I think that by default if there's nothing else in the cell it should center align the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see from the [Table Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747133.aspx), table elements can't be absolutely positioned relative to the area of their "cell" boundaries. The only solution is using a nested UI container:

```
<TableCell>
    <BlockUIContainer>
        <Border Width="300">
            <FlowDocumentReader HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="150">
                <FlowDocument>
                    <Table x:Name="nestedTable" Background="Blue">
                        <!--  table content -->
                    </Table>
                </FlowDocument>
            </FlowDocumentReader>
        </Border>
    </BlockUIContainer>
</TableCell>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried **TableCell.TextAlignment** property?

Comment: it aligns the text contents within the Tablecell not the table!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than making the table the contents of the cell, wrap the nested table with something like a `Grid` that does support alignment within its bounds.

Comment: I cannot add Grid to FixedDocument, can i?

Answer (score -1):

Once your codes are ok, then this might work well.

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = myTable ;
this.dataGridView1.Columns["MyColumnName"].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
```

I hope you get clear by
PARAMU

Comment: have u read my code?????? First tell me what is Table, DataTable, DataSet, DataGridView, ListView...

Read before answering!